# Can i decode twice with same pymodbus BinaryPayloadDecoder object?

Tags: python, modbus, pymodbus

I have a small test program that will eventually use pymodbus to communicate with our controller. Im using BinaryPayloadDecoder to convert each pair of registers to both int and float since some register pairs are floats and  some are int. But decode fails on second attempt to decode from same BinaryPayloadDecoder object.

```
from pymodbus.payload import BinaryPayloadDecoder
from pymodbus.constants import Endian

registers = [0x41b7, 0x7873]
decoder = BinaryPayloadDecoder.fromRegisters(registers, byteorder=Endian.BIG, wordorder=Endian.BIG)
myfloat = decoder.decode_32bit_float()
print("reg = ", myfloat)
myint = decoder.decode_32bit_int()
print("reg = ", myint)
```

Produces

```
reg =  22.933813095092773
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\jwoods7\source\hello\test.py", line 8, in <module>
    myint = decoder.decode_32bit_int()
  File "c:\Users\jwoods7\source\hello\.venv\lib\site-packages\pymodbus\payload.py", line 412, in decode_32bit_int
    handle = self._unpack_words(fstring, handle)
  File "c:\Users\jwoods7\source\hello\.venv\lib\site-packages\pymodbus\payload.py", line 342, in _unpack_words
    handle = unpack(f"!{wc_value}H", handle)
struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 4 bytes
```

However if i create the decoder object again before trying to convert to int32.

```
from pymodbus.payload import BinaryPayloadDecoder
from pymodbus.constants import Endian

registers = [0x41b7, 0x7873]
decoder = BinaryPayloadDecoder.fromRegisters(registers, byteorder=Endian.BIG, wordorder=Endian.BIG)
myfloat = decoder.decode_32bit_float()
print("reg = ", myfloat)
decoder = BinaryPayloadDecoder.fromRegisters(registers, byteorder=Endian.BIG, wordorder=Endian.BIG)
myint = decoder.decode_32bit_int()
print("reg = ", myint)
```

it works. So a BinaryPayloadDecoder object cannot convert more than once?

```
reg =  22.933813095092773
reg =  1102542963
```

Comment: The way you currently have it, you're trying to decode a float *followed by* an int.  A quick look at the PyModbus documentation shows a `.reset()` method - "Reset the decoder pointer back to the start" - that should let you apply both formats to the same data.

Answer (score 1):

The following will provide the result you are looking for:

```py
from pymodbus.payload import BinaryPayloadDecoder
from pymodbus.constants import Endian

registers = [0x41b7, 0x7873]
decoder = BinaryPayloadDecoder.fromRegisters(registers, byteorder=Endian.BIG, wordorder=Endian.BIG)
myfloat = decoder.decode_32bit_float()
print("reg = ", myfloat)
decoder.reset()
myint = decoder.decode_32bit_int()
print("reg = ", myint)
```

Output:

```
reg =  22.933813095092773
reg =  1102542963
```

As noted in the comment above, each call to a decode function (e.g. [`decode_32bit_float`](https://github.com/pymodbus-dev/pymodbus/blob/dev/pymodbus/payload.py#L433)) advances an internal pointer such that the next call to a decode function will begin reading AFTER the data already decoded (allowing you to extract, for example, multiple 32 bit floats from the binary data).

This means that the following will also have the desired result (assumes you pulled 4 registers):

```py
registers = [0x41b7, 0x7873, 0x41b7, 0x7873]
decoder = BinaryPayloadDecoder.fromRegisters(registers, byteorder=Endian.BIG, wordorder=Endian.BIG)
myfloat = decoder.decode_32bit_float()
print("reg = ", myfloat)
myint = decoder.decode_32bit_int()
print("reg = ", myint)
```

Calling [`reset()`](https://github.com/pymodbus-dev/pymodbus/blob/dev/pymodbus/payload.py#L433) resets that pointer (the next `decode_*` call will read from the start of the buffer).

Comment: Thanks. I completely missed that method.